# ms access findfirst goes to new record instead of displaying specified record

Tags: ms-access, vba

This code was working fine then suddenly starting displaying 'new' instead of the specified record. I can't think of anything I did that would make this suddenly stop working as expected. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub cboHotel_AfterUpdate()

Dim rs As Object
Dim strCriteria As String

Set rs = Me.Recordset.Clone

strCriteria = "[EventName] = '" & Me.cboEvent & "' And [Hotel] = '" & Me.cboHotel & "'"

rs.FindFirst strCriteria

If Not rs.EOF Then Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark

Forms!Submissions!TabCtl1.Visible = True

Forms!Submissions!EventName.SetFocus

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried `Dim rs As DAO.Recordset`?

Comment: hi, @ChristopherD. i had not but just did and no change. i built a simple new form with the exact same code and it worked but uugghh to have to do that for the entire form. wth happened? grr

Comment: Ugh, figured it out. I had form>properties>data>data entry set to Yes and it needs to be No. thanks for replying @ChristopherD.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

form>properties>data>data entry needs to be set to No